# Настройка приложения под размер экрана Iphone 5s

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте.
Тестирую приложение на своем айфоне, программа открывается на размер экрана айфона 4, а у меня 5s.
Как исправить положение, никак не могу найти настройки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сплешскрин должен быть под пятерку, тогда будет открываться нормально.